# Android app that's able to take photos, get the geographic information such as GPS coordinates, and export to a spreadsheet large-scale

Tags: android, database, camera, gps, gps-tracking

Long story short, I am working on a project where we have to take photos of thousands of machines and have GPS proof of that saved in a database.

The best I've found yet is the "Smart GPS Location" app, which generates a CSV file with the information that I need. However, since we're working with hundreds of people doing the photo taking, it is not viable since each phone is going to generate a different CSV file, and they are not centralized.

Are there any Android apps that can achieve this?

Comment: If your using a phone, and have location turned ON for you camera app.  As long as reception is available the camera app should automatically embed the GPS info into the pictures EXIF metadata.  Thus using exiftool you could extract this info.  You could probably even write a python script to automate some of it.  Would this kind of thing be acceptable?

Comment: I think it would work but I have no idea how to do that. I'm going to do some research, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use an app GPS TRACKER
Suitable for a type of water that I have not tested for safety, but my brother is working on it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Credit:  https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2017/06/extract-gps-tags-from-photographs-into.html

Download exiftool first, of course.

Open up a Windows Command Prompt. In the prompt, type in the command.

Extract GPS tags from photographs into a CSV file using Exiftool

Depending on which exiftool you have the (-k) thing may or may not be necessary.

```
C:\> "exiftool(-k).exe" -n -gpslongitude -gpslatitude -gpstimestamp -csv D:\MyDocuments\temp\somephotos >outgps.csv

Note:
-n means to print out as numbers only
-csv prints out csv including the file path and name
-D points to the folder directory of the photographs to extract
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Android phone will embed the location tags into the photos automatically if you do the following

- Enable GPS
- Give GPS permission to the camera app
- In the camera App, turn on `Settings` -> `Camera Settings` -> `Location tags`

Then you can use a tool such as 'exiftool` mentioned in another answer, to extract the information.

[image]